# PDFs generated using PDFBoxUtil giving error at the time of first print command

Tags: pdf-generation

```
The code used is:
public static PDDocument getPDFDocument(InputStream pdfLocation, String xfdf) {
    FDFDocument xfdfDocument = null;
    PDDocument pdfDocument;
    try {
        if (pdfLocation != null && xfdf != null
                && xfdf.trim().length() != 0) {

            pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdfLocation);
            xfdfDocument = FDFDocument.loadXFDF(new   ByteArrayInputStream(
                    xfdf.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
            PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
            acroForm.setCacheFields(true);
            acroForm.importFDF(xfdfDocument);

            try {
                // plog 96545 edit font size and spacing
                PDDocument tempDoc = acroForm.getDocument();
                PDAcroForm tempForm = tempDoc.getDocumentCatalog()
                        .getAcroForm();

                for (int i = 0; i < tempForm.getFields().size(); i++) {
                    PDField field = (PDField) tempForm.getFields().get(i);
                    if (field.getValue() != null) {
                        setAppearanceValue(field, field.getValue());
                    }

                }

                acroForm = tempForm;
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                _log
                        .error("Error occured while changing font size of form - "
                                + e1.getMessage());
            }
            // end plog 96545

            PDDocument mergedDocument = acroForm.getDocument();
            return mergedDocument;

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new bnsException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (xfdfDocument != null) {
            try {
                xfdfDocument.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                _log.warn(e);
            }
        }
    }
}


public static void setAppearanceValue(PDField field, String apValue)
        throws IOException {
    _log.debug("Inside setAppearanceValue method ");
    float fontSize = 9;
    float lowerLeftMargin = -4;
    PDAnnotationWidget widget = field.getWidget();

    PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = widget.getAppearance();
    if (appearance == null) {
        appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
        widget.setAppearance(appearance);
    }

    Map normalAppearance = appearance.getNormalAppearance();
    PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = (PDAppearanceStream) normalAppearance
            .get("default");

    if (appearanceStream != null) {
        appearanceStream.getBoundingBox().setLowerLeftY(-4);
        List tokens = getStreamTokens(appearanceStream);

        if (tokens != null) {

            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(output);

            boolean foundString = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
                if (tokens.get(i) instanceof COSString) {
                    foundString = true;
                    COSString drawnString = ((COSString) tokens.get(i));
                    drawnString.reset();
                    drawnString.append(apValue.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                }
            }

            int setFontIndex = tokens
                    .indexOf(PDFOperator.getOperator("Tf"));
            /*
             * COSName cosFontName = (COSName)tokens.get( setFontIndex-1 );
             * _log.debug("cosFontName is "+cosFontName);
             */
            tokens.set(setFontIndex - 1, new COSFloat(fontSize));

            if (foundString) {

                writer.writeTokens(tokens);
            }

            writeToStream(output.toByteArray(), appearanceStream);
            // added
            output.close();

        } else {

        }

    }

}
```

I am getting below for the first time giving print command.

"An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. please contact the person who created the pdf document to correct the problem".

Print out is coming very fine and second time print out command not giving any error.

Actually in my application, I have the PDF template on which we populate the data. The above issue occurs only when data is populated and not with the empty template.I am using Adobe Reader XI(11.0.01). Please let me know if you need any more specifics.Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please supply the PDF without data, the PDF with data, and your code using PDFBoxUtil.

Comment: Thanks for responding mkl but could you please tell me how to upload the pdf here as I could not find a place to upload it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot. You can only upload images here, and even that might be limited while you have a very low rep. Usually, if PDFs for inspecting or reproducing issues are required, the files are provided via file sharing services (preferably drop box or google drive public shares; and not services requiring you to first register or which hide the actual DOWNLOAD button in tons of ads).

Comment: @mkl:sorry for the late response.I have uploaded the PDFs on google drive and you can access them on the following link:1.Populated:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B01Ovp-koEi9NmFwZUx4Nl92YXFla25OOHdJT0JaNEFzWTJF/edit?usp=sharing
2.Blank:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B01Ovp-koEi9NmFwZUx4Nl92YXFla25OOHdJT0JaNEFzWTJF/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You have posted the same link twice.

Comment: @mkl:Hey extremely sry for putting up the response so late. Actually the issue got resolved. earlier I was using pdfbox-app-1.7.1.jar which I replaced by pdfbox-app-1.8.4.jar and the issue is resolved. Thanks a lot for the co-operation though.

Comment: i would suggest you make that solution an answer to your question and eventually accept it (it might take sometime before you can accept your own answer, though).